# How can I add new Reference service on WebProject visual studio

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a WebProject in Visual Studio 2013. So I have add new Services. In the link field I have add this url:

```
https://servername/nsisr/PianoService?wsdl
```

then I have this error message:

```
Errore durante il download di 'https://serverName/nsisr/PianoService?wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Richiesta non riuscita con stato HTTP 404: Not Found.
I metadati contengono un riferimento che non può essere risolto: 'https://serverName/nsisr/PianoService?wsdl'.
Il server non è stato in grado di fornire una risposta significativa. Ciò potrebbe essere causato da un contratto non corrispondente, un arresto prematuro della sessione o un errore server interno.
Se il servizio è definito nella soluzione corrente, provare a compilare la soluzione e ad aggiungere nuovamente il riferimento al servizio.
```

How can I fixed it?

regards

Comment: Your error message has HTTP 404, i.e., the resource is not found. Can you navigate to the service in your browser without any issues?

Comment: If I insert this link https://servername/nsisr/PianoService?wsdl on my browser, I can read the wsdl.
For me the problem is the content of wsdl, I don't understand why, visual studio read also /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata